# Pager disappears when adding "GROUP BY" in the SQL query

Tags: theming, paging

Drupal pager disappears when I add `GROUP BY` to the query.

This code works.

```
$countSql = "SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM journal ";
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM journal";    

$result = pager_query($sql, 1, 0, null, $countSql);
theme_pager(NULL, 10)
```

This code doesn't show the pager.

```
$countSql = "SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM journal ";
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM journal GROUP BY id";

$result = pager_query($sql, 1, 0, null, $countSql);  
theme_pager(NULL, 10)
```

What is it wrong with the latter code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query with the `GROUP BY` is incorrect, MySQL is lax enough to let you write this kind of queries but it is by [no way recommended](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html). When you use a `GROUP BY` clause you should group all the columns without an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Also if you put a `GROUP BY` in your query, you should also include it in your count query. Generally a brutal way to make the count query is to put it this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM journal";
$countSql = "SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM ($sql) ";
```

Try to modify your queries and amend your question with further precisions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, u r right in sql server i cannot use group by like this but mysql let me do this,also that is not actual query i m going to post my actual query in my own answer

Comment: If you want, you can correct this behaviour by secifying the option [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) in MySQL configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I need distinct journals, and their IDs must be in article table; the article table can have multiple journal IDs, and I need two article columns.

```
SELECT  j.nid AS journal_nid, j.title AS journal_title, j.id AS journal_id, a.is_epub, a.nid AS article_nid, j.image_file_name
FROM journal j
INNER JOIN article a ON j.id = a.journal_id ". $condition." GROUP BY j.id ORDER BY j.title ASC
```

I modified my query, and the pager appears.

```
SELECT  j.id AS journal_id, j.nid AS journal_nid, j.title AS journal_title, j.image_file_name,
(select max(nid) from article where journal_id = j.id) AS article_nid,
(select max(is_epub) from article where journal_id = j.id) is_epub
FROM journal j
WHERE j.id IN (SELECT journal_id FROM article)
```