# If a pager is missing, then appears when using another theme, does that narrow the problem to the original theme?

Tags: theming, paging

I have a pager missing from one page, while visible on another. These pages are generated by my custom module. I'm working with a custom theme that's been hacked together (wasn't me!) When I switch the theme to Bartik everything works as expected.

Here is the query function:

```
function query_activities($tid = NULL, $did = NULL) {
  $record_count = variable_get('promo_list_count');
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')->extend('PagerDefault');
  $query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'));
  if ($tid) {
    $query->leftJoin('taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'ti.nid = n.nid');
    $query->condition('ti.tid', $tid);
  }
  $query->condition('n.type', 'activity_promo_list');
  $query->condition('n.status', 1);
  $query->groupBy('n.nid');
  $query->orderBy('n.sticky', 'DESC');
  $query->orderBy('n.promote', 'DESC');
  $query->orderBy('n.changed', 'DESC');
  $query->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC');
  $query->limit($record_count);
  $results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
  return $results;
```

I have a function that wraps the query results in theme arrays and can post the whole thing if needed (it's 120 lines) but I think the only relevant part is:

```
  $content['pager'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'pager',
  '#weight' => $count,
  '#quantity' => 5,
  );
  krumo($content['pager']);
  return $content;
```

The krumo() dump shows the pager array populated on both pages (pager visible & pager missing).

Does this narrow the problem to theme layer?

What should I look for to fix or diagnose the missing pager?

Comment: It's (almost) definitely a theme layer problem, does the hacked-together-theme contain a function called `THEMENAME_pager`?

Comment: No, I saw a few other questions refer to THEMENAME_pager, so I searched for this (actually searched pager) and nothing out of the ordinary came up.

Comment: How does your module generate and pass the pager to the page?

Comment: @sheena_d I updated the question to include some code :)

Comment: have you looked at the HTML source of the page as outputted to a browser? Is the pager markup there? .. just thinking it could be as simple as a CSS rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled on [tostinni's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/18294/5569) in [Pager disappears when adding "GROUP BY" in the SQL query](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18289/drupal-pager-disappears-when-adding-group-by-in-sql).

> Your query with the `GROUP BY` is incorrect, MySQL is lax enough to let you write this kind of queries but it is by no way recommended. When you use a `GROUP BY` clause you should group all the columns without a aggregate function.

I then fixed two queries that have poorly formed `GROUP BY`s, but my pager was still missing. I bust out [Devel's](http://drupal.org/project/devel) query logging feature; the offending SQL query resulted to be used by the [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module. I checked the bug reports for that module, and found the one about that query: [Grouping error" when creating a simple queue (PostgreSQL)](http://drupal.org/node/1475396).